# Can a Sunni Muslim offer prayers in a Shiite mosque?

Tags: sharia, salat, shia-sunni, masjid

Many peoples says don't offer salat/prayer in a Shiite mosque if you are Sunni Muslim.

Is it impermissible to pray in a Shiite mosque?

Comment: The whole earth is a masjid for us and so there's no issue if you go and pray there. However, for you own security and safety, its better that you don't. Also if there are pictures and images of people in the masjid then one cannot pray there or there is a grave in their.

Comment: In Iran there is not important that the mosque you are praying is for Sunnis or Shias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Saying prayers in mosque of Shia and Sunni is totally unrestricted. Even saying prayers in church is allowed (if it has no danger for your religion).

Also the whole world is created by *Allah*. No one can restrict from for praying to him by building anything.

But it's better to pray to Allah in a mosque because of hadith from prophet Mohammad(صلى الله عليه وسلم):

> Mosques are houses of Allah in our world.

and another hadith from prophet that says:

> Mosque is home of every Muslim.

So there is no difference between Shia and Sunni in this hadith.

<sup>(Sorry for no source for hadith. I couldn't find any English source for them.)</sup>

Comment: --"The whole earth is a mosque for us"--
"Mosques are houses of Allah in our world"--"Mosque is home of every Muslim" (I got my answer brothers, Jazak Allāh - May Allāh reward you [with] goodness)

Comment: Could you at least give the citation in Arabic?

Comment: There were no Shia at the time of the prophet, and "Sunni" is a basically a term to recognize those who follow the "Sunna", which is in layman terms the prophet's habits and sayings, contrary to following other introductions into Islam that is not part of it, e.g. "Shia", the answer "no difference between Shia and Sunni in this hadith" is therefore fallacious, not necessarily wrong but its deduction is not based on correct evidence.